# multi-thread matrices multiplication in C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

I am doing matrices multiplication in C on Linux and specifically using pthread. Here is my code. It failed to run and it only print out the empty matrix once and said segmentation fault. Can anyone point out the mistake? Thank you.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 9
int A[3][3] = {{2,5,6},{2,12,10},{6,1,8}};
int B[3][3] = {{7,5,1},{17,0,13},{3,2,5}};
int answer[3][3]={0};

void *multiply (void *param);
void print_matrix (int m[3][3]);

void print_matrix (int m[3][3]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d\t ", m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}

void *multiply (void *param) {
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                    for(k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                            answer[i][j] +=  A[i][k] *  B[k][j];
                    }
            }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

int main() 
{
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) { 
        pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of attributes for the thread */
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);/* get the default attributes */
        pthread_create(&tid[i],&attr,multiply,NULL);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
        print_matrix(answer);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging on your own? Using a debugger and/or debug print statements. What did you find?

Comment: How are you passing your data to your threads? How are you preventing race conditions as 9 threads manipulate the same data at the same time? How are you ensuring that you are not multiplying the two arrays 9 times?

Comment: Why are you running 9 threads of `multiply()` doing the same thing and writing on the same variable?

Comment: hmmm...9 threads doing the same thing and ...race conditions

Answer (score 0):

You are running all 9 threads at same time which are accessing same global variables. This can create problem. Try imposing a small time delay just after calling a thread. `sleep(1);` can do the trick. Or use some mechanism like mutex/ semaphore